# How to validate filetype in rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In the frontend I want to have a simple file filter for uploading the documents say: pdf and txt files should be allowed for upload / indexing. How I am supposed to handle this, in the .rb file or I should do this differently via javascript? 
This is the current rails controller how I handle file upload.

```
def create
    if params[:files].present?
      flash = {}
      flash[:notice] = []

      params[:files].each do |file|
        document = UserDocument.new({
          user: current_user,
          status: 'processing',
          file_name: file.original_filename,
          meta: Document::Meta.new(
            title: file.original_filename
          )
        })

        if duplicate = document_duplicate(current_user, file.original_filename)
          flash[:notice] << { title: t('.notice.title'), message: t('.notice.message', file_name: file.original_filename, existing_path: duplicate.full_path) }
        end

        if save_temporary_file(file) && document.save
          UploadDocumentWorker.perform_async(document.id, temporary_file_path(file.original_filename))

          flash[:success] = t('.success', count: params[:files].length)
        else
          flash[:error] = t('.error', count: params[:files].length)
        end
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = t('.error.nofile')
    end

    redirect_to user_documents_path, flash: flash
  end

  # Destroys a single document
  def destroy
    if @document.destroy
      redirect_to user_documents_path, flash: { success: t('.success') }
    else
      redirect_to user_documents_path, flash: { error: t('.error') }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the file type at both ends.

In rails, I've found the two most effective methods are Ruby FileMagic:
https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic

Or by shelling out the file type:

```
file -b --mime-type myfile.pdf

=> application/pdf
```

You should set up a filetype whitelist in your controller/a service your controller can use, which asserts the file type is valid by comparing the output of one of the two tools I listed above with your whitelisted **file types**, and the **file extension** of the file you've received.

On the front-end, you could do something like the following using jQuery:

```
var allowedExtension = ["txt", "pdf"];
$.each(inputFile.files, function() {
    extName = this.name.split('.').pop();
    if ($.inArray(extName, allowedExtension) == -1) {extError=true;};
  })
```

The reason for this is two-fold:

On the client-side, it's quick and easy to make a basic assertion about file type.  This means that users get feedback as soon as possible, rather than making a whole round trip from client to server to realise their file type is appropriate.

The server side validation is important, because our front-end implementation is fairly naïve, and easy to bypass.  Having validation at the back-end makes your application more robust.